# Creating a DPI and Resolution Independant GUI

Tags: opengl, gui, resolution

How would one best go about it? Assuming I'm using OpenGL to do all the drawing.

It seems like the best approach is to have the GUI elements maintain the same physical size regardless of the screen it is displayed on.It seems that Windows will act as if you had a screen with 72 DPI regardless of its actual size unless you specifically request tell it that you handle high DPI cases. Which would greatly simplify things, does this hold for Linux as well?

Does things change between running things in Windowed mode versus fullscreen? It seems like it should, as the Window changes size depending on resultion while in fullscreen the image is always the same size, just with less or more density!

Comment: Where I work we specify all GUI element sizes as mm on display. This is hard for different DPI as some displays just dont know that much about themselves (sometimes they do) but it is really the closest you get to customer requirements and expectations. I hate glueing my eyes on high DPI displays for no good reason. The conversion is just a projection matrix away.

Answer (score 1):

Windows:

Imho, one should completely avoid fullscreen mode. There is no longer any performance advantage with it, those days are gone.

If you want to cover the entire screen, just create a borderless and captionless window with fullscreen dimensions. This gives you advantages:

- Only one set of code: If going directly fullscreen at program start, one reacts once only on a screen resize, if going to windowed mode, the same code reacts each time a resize event occurs. (And btw, i believe the video memory almost always gets badly beaten from device resizes, so prepare to re-construct various render surfaces).
- Easier development and debugging (multiple windows handy/accessible).
- You can easily extend the application to cover multiple screens, when the user has an "extended desktop" (when one can move mouse cursor from one display to another). Just make the window 6000 px wide for 3 screens and place it at x=-2000 or likewise. Windows provides an API for monitor coordinates & placement.
- Also from the users perspective positive: Allows to place other windows topmost (you must react on lostfocus or hasfocus).
- Be a good to the hardware. Old fullscreen feels destructive...

The easy going way is to not scale. Applications usually try to place their elements starting from upper lefthand corner. Same with a game GUI that may occupy a larger piece of the screen. BUT ofc one can justify isolated screen elements also right & bottom, as long as they aren't too big. Hence a good scaling would be to not alter icon sizes, fonts, picture sizes, etc. but indeed place them nicely according to screen pixels.

Then tell users with too few pixels (and too old hardware) to go grab something newer. Do not support anything too old-fashioned, rather aim at supporting what there will be 3.14 years from now :-).